# XCode: Unknown type name 'SCREEN', only when building for release, in file 'unctrl.h'

Tags: xcode, macos-sierra, bridging-header

XCode finds the error in this file:

```
/opt/local/include/unctrl.h
```

Message: Unknown type name 'SCREEN'

`/opt/local/include/` has to be in my header search paths. It makes no difference to add `/usr/include/` before it in header search paths. XCode still insists on using the version found in `/opt/local/include/` anyway. The version found under `/usr/include/` does not have the line which triggers the error, but XCode is unwilling to use that version.

XCode version: 8.3.3

The error occurs when compiling a Bridging header file, for a macos application.

"Clean Product" makes no difference.

The error occurs only when setting the macos deployment target to 10.12, and only in release configuration.

- deployment target 10.11 - debug build - no error
- deployment target 10.11 - release build - no error
- deployment target 10.12 - debug build - no error
- deployment target **10.12** - **release build** - ERROR

Comment: I upgraded MacPorts and it fixed things for me: `sudo port selfupdate; sudo port upgrade outdated`

Answer (score 5):

What's happening is that you are getting a mixture of header files, some from MacPorts installs, others from the system, and they are not compatible. It's loading the SDK.12 version of `ncurses.h` (which defined SCREEN *after* loading `unctrl.h`), but the MacPorts version of `unctrl.h` (which expects SCREEN to be defined).

I finally resolved this problem by specifying the MacPorts include directory as a system include directory, so it would be used for <> includes as well as "" includes by specifying the include search path:

```
-cxx-isystem/opt/local/include
```

rather than

```
-I/opt/local/include
```

Comment: In addition, I had to set "Enable Modules" to "No" in the Xcode build settings.

Comment: I resolved this by removing macports entirely and homebrew instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out. The problem was I had several sub-projects with frameworks, and these were set with deployment target less than macos 10.12.

However, when setting deployment target of the main project to 10.11, the sub-projects would still have mixed deployment targets, as some of them had deployment target of 10.10. For some reason this didn't matter with deployment target of the main project set to 10.11, only when deployment target of the main project was set to 10.12.

Whatever the reason, setting deployment target to 10.12 for all sub-projects and the main project resolved the issue.